# how can i use a uniform sql for insert when come with default value and null str in user inputs with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, integer, default

Here I have a mysql table like this:

```
create table abc (
    name varchar(20) not null,
    value int not null default 20
)
```

and in the php page, I wanna use a uniform sql for all insert like this:

```
insert into abc values('first name', '30')
```

but sometimes, there maybe someone dont input a value and the insert sql will be like

```
insert into abc values('a name', '')
```

and why can't it work? The mysql says `Incorrect integer value: '' for column...` and 
I want it give the default value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert a not-integer-value into your field if you have declared it as an integer with `NOT NULL`.

1) Either control the value via your code if you want to use the same `INSERT` statement in both cases...

```
$var = 30;
$SQL = "INSERT INTO abc () VALUES('first name', '".$var."')";
```

2) ... or have two different `INSERT`s for your default values:

```
/* for the default value */
$SQL = "INSERT INTO abc (somefield) VALUES('first name')";
```

Comment: yeah, your answer can solve the problem, but i have told that only some time the field is '', and value is not the only field in the situlation, there may be a lot, i do not wanna write so many $var and give it a value and check if the field is ''

Comment: Again, you're trying to insert a non-integer into an integer field, that's what your error message is telling you. Either you deal with it with putting proper values into this part of the Insert-Statement, or you avoid it (because you want the default value in this fiels) while not declaring this field in the fieldset parameter between your tablename and VALUES.